# Which linux should be chosen for LAMP

Tags: lamp

I am trying to learn LAMP on Fedora linux os.
can any one suggest which fedora os should i choose for 
learning
1-fedora 19 desktop(latest)
2-fedora 19 kde
3-fedora 19 lxde
4-fedora 19 xfce

i am new to linux.
or i should use ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to linux, I would recommend Ubuntu as that is a popular Linux distro and is well documented and has a super active community that can help you out if/when you get stuck :)